# Event VSCode API CodeAction accepted

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to trigger some code whenever a CodeAction (QuickFix - lightbulb) is applied?

Inside my CustomActionProvider that implements `vscode.CodeActionProvider`

```ts
public provideCodeActions(document: vscode.TextDocument, range: vscode.Range): vscode.CodeAction[] | undefined {
    let ifPowershell = this.isAtIfPS(document, range);
    if (ifPowershell[0] === "true") {
        //Tenemos que calcular el Range, para hacer el replace
        let line = document.lineAt(range.start.line);
        let startIndex = line.firstNonWhitespaceCharacterIndex;
        let range2 = new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(range.start.line, startIndex), line.range.end);
        //El texto que va a remplazar al código existente
        let fix = `if (${ifPowershell[1]} ${ifPowershell[2]} ${ifPowershell[3]})`;
        return [this.createFix(document, range2, fix)];
    }

    //Si llegamos aquí es que no hay 
    return;
}

private createFix(document: vscode.TextDocument, range: vscode.Range, replace: string): vscode.CodeAction {
    const fix = new vscode.CodeAction(`Convert to ${replace}`, vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix);
    fix.edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
    fix.edit.replace(document.uri, new vscode.Range(range.start, range.end), replace);
    return fix;
}
```

I can already suggest this

[image]

Both `if (var -eq 0)` and `if (var == 0)` will work, but they are different in performance. So, the recommendation is to use the `==` operator instead of `-eq`

Now... I want to count how many users accepted this quickfix, and I already have an API to log that in a database.

The question is: *how to code an event, callback or some function that will be triggered whenever the quickfix is 'accepted' by the user?*

Comment: Are you asking for in general when someone runs your extension's quickfix/lightbulb or are you wanting an injection for tslint itself?

Comment: The event, when someone runs the quickfix/lightbulb

Comment: So your specific extensions?

Comment: Correct, I already have an extension that offers quickfixes to the user. The issue here is I would like run some code when the user applies the changes suggested by the lightbulb.

Comment: I already solved the actual quickfix. But I also want to log in a database that some user accepted the given suggestion.

Comment: Can you share the code you have?

Comment: I edited the post, with an extract of the CodeActionProvider, and a longer description of the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CodeAction.command` for this.

First register an internal command:

```ts
vscode.commands.registerCommand('_myExt.didApplyFix', () => { 
    // handle fix applied
})
```

Then use this command on the code action you return:

```ts
const action = new vscode.CodeAction('action title');
action.command = { command: '_myExt.didApplyFix', title: 'action title' }
```

The command will be invoked whenever the fix is applied

Comment: I edited the answer to add that the command can take arguments to pass some more details about the fix that was applied, maybe the line number, the type of fix, severity level, etc. Thank you!